# Is it possible to resume where you last were in UIwebView Xcode 5

Tags: ios, ios7, webview, xcode5

Hi im am currently building a app where i have multiple webViews with different sites. My question is if you can when you click a view and surf on it and the switch to a different view and the back to the first view resume where you were and not having to start over just because the view reloaded? I now the question is kind of messy but if you could help it would be awsome! im using a regular UIvewView

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.mywebsite.com"];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[webView loadRequest:requestURL];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate :[How does iOS 6 UIWebView state restoration work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587983/how-does-ios-6-uiwebview-state-restoration-work)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you can just save the last url you went to and reload that page? I think you can do that with NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use NSUserDefaults or state restoration if you're just looking to save the page address between views.  (If you're looking to save the data between app uses, then yes, you could store the url string using NSUserDefaults.)

To store the value in your app delegate for global access, declare the variable in your app delegate's .h:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSUrl *currentUrl;
```

To access the variable in a class, create an instance of the app delegate in the .m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

AppDelegate *mainDelegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Then instead of using:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.mywebsite.com"];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[webView loadRequest:requestURL];
```

initially set the `currentUrl` value before `webView` is ever opened:

```
mainDelegate.currentUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.mywebsite.com"];
```

and prior to each `webView` open, initialize the NSUrlRequest to:

```
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:mainDelegate.currentUrl];
```

Finally, to store the current address of each `webView` upon closing, use:

```
mainDelegate.currentUrl = webView.request.URL;
```